# Get tags from Radiobuttons in ListView Android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, android-radiogroup

I have a custom **listView** built with **ArrayAdapter**. In **ListView** each item contents a **TextView** and a **RadioGroup** (with 4 **RadioButton**). I can choose one **RadioButton** to be selected for each list item. On the bottom of **ListView** i have a footer with button. What i want is to get all data when i click on button like this:

name1 - 1

name2 - 3

name3 - 2

name4 - 3

...

First column - Text from **TextView**

Second column - Tag of selected **RadioButton**

Atcivity with view:

```
public class MarksAdd  extends ListActivity {
    ArrayList<String> itemlist = new ArrayList<String>();
    private Context context = null;
    private ListView listView;
    private Button BtnDone;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.marks_add);


        Intent intent = getIntent();
        int day = intent.getIntExtra("day", 0);
        int month = intent.getIntExtra("month", 0);
        int year = intent.getIntExtra("year", 0);


        String dayStr = String.valueOf(day);
        String monthStr = String.valueOf(month);
        String yearStr = String.valueOf(year);


        if (day != 0) {
            if(dayStr.length()==1){
                dayStr = "0"+dayStr;
            }
            if(monthStr.length()==1){
                monthStr = "0"+monthStr;
            }
            yearStr = yearStr.substring(2);
            String date = dayStr+"."+monthStr+"."+yearStr;
            Toast.makeText(this, date, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


        final ArrayAdapter<Model> adapter = new InteractiveArrayAdapter(this,
                getModel());





        listView = getListView();
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        listView.addFooterView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_footer, null), null, false);

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        BtnDone = (Button) findViewById(R.id.markListBtn);
        BtnDone.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //get Values ?????

            }



        });


    }

    private List<Model> getModel() {

        List<Model> list = new ArrayList<Model>();

        dbHelper sql = new dbHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = sql.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(
                PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext()).getString("group", ""), new String[]{
                        "Id", "Name"},
                null, // The columns for the WHERE clause
                null, // The values for the WHERE clause
                null, // don't group the rows
                null, // don't filter by row groups
                "Name ASC" // The sort order
        );

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            // GET COLUMN INDICES + VALUES OF THOSE COLUMNS
            int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("Id"));
            String name = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex("Name"));
            list.add(get(name));

        }
        cursor.close();





        // Initially select one of the items


        return list;
    }

    private Model get(String question) {
        return new Model(question);
    }



}
```

ArrayAdapter:

```
public class InteractiveArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Model> {
    private final List<Model> list;
    private final Activity context;

    public InteractiveArrayAdapter(Activity context, List<Model> list) {
        super(context, R.layout.simple_list_item1_marks, list);
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        TextView t = null;
        RadioGroup group;

        ViewHolder(View v) {
            t = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.personName);
            group = (RadioGroup) v.findViewById(R.id.myRgroup);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.simple_list_item1_marks, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder(v);
            v.setTag(holder);
            final View finalV = v;
            holder.group
                    .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group,
                                                     int checkedId) {
                            Integer pos = (Integer) group.getTag(); // To identify the Model object i get from the RadioGroup with getTag()
                            //  an integer representing the actual position
                            Model element = list.get(pos);
                            switch (checkedId) { //set the Model to hold the answer the user picked
                                case R.id.rb1:
                                    element.current = Model.ANSWER_ONE_SELECTED;
                                    break;
                                case R.id.rb2:
                                    element.current = Model.ANSWER_TWO_SELECTED;
                                    break;
                                case R.id.rb3:
                                    element.current = Model.ANSWER_THREE_SELECTED;
                                    break;
                                case R.id.rb4:
                                    element.current = Model.ANSWER_FOUR_SELECTED;
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    element.current = Model.NONE; // Something was wrong set to the default
                            }

                        }
                    });
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }
        holder.group.setTag(position); // I passed the current position as a tag

        holder.t.setText(list.get(position).question); // Set the question body

        if (list.get(position).current != Model.NONE) {
            RadioButton r = (RadioButton) holder.group.getChildAt(list
                    .get(position).current);
            r.setChecked(true);
        } else {
            holder.group.clearCheck(); // This is required because although the Model could have the current
            // position to NONE you could be dealing with a previous row where
            // the user already picked an answer.

        }
        return v;
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public class Model {
    String question; // hold the question
    int current = NONE; // hold the answer picked by the user, initial is NONE(see below)
    public static final int NONE = 1000; // No answer selected
    public static final int ANSWER_ONE_SELECTED = 0; // first answer selected
    public static final int ANSWER_TWO_SELECTED = 1; // second answer selected
    public static final int ANSWER_THREE_SELECTED = 2; // third answer selected
    public static final int ANSWER_FOUR_SELECTED = 3; // forth answer selected

    public Model(String question) {
        this.question = question;
    }
}
```

I was doing this according to [that tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#listadvanced_interactive) with some changes. Actualy i'm realy newbie in development, so im asking you to help me. Sorry if my question is not correct, my english is not realy good.

Well be very thankfull for any help here.

Comment: when you say Data, do you mean the date? and what do you want to do with the data?

Comment: @BasselSerio No, i mean data. Values from textView and from radioGroup. Wanna store them in database later.

Answer (score 0):

The first thought would be to iterate over the `ListView` and get the checked button in each row. This won't actually work because ListView does not contain all of its children all of the time.

Instead, you should store the checked item when the user actually makes a selection. Then when you press the button, you already have all the data stored and don't have to iterate over the `ListView`. Also, having the current selections saved this way will be useful if you scroll back up the list because you can set the current checked radio button for previous items in `getView()`.

Let's assume the row layout has this in it:

```
<RadioGroup android:id="@+id/radio_group" ... >
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_button_1" ... />
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_button_2" ... />
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_button_3" ... />
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_button_4" ... />
</RadioGroup>
```

In your adapter's `getView()`, give the RadioGroup an `OnCheckedChangedListener` defined in the adapter itself (so you have one `OnCheckedChangedListener` instead of one per row). Tag the RadioGroup with the position of the list item so that you can differentiate it in the callback.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ...
    Model model = getItem(position);
    int checkedId = ... //figure out checked id from model
    viewHolder.group.check(checkedId);
    viewHolder.group.setTag(position);
    viewHolder.group.setOnCheckedChangedListener(checkChangedListener);
    ...
}

private OnCheckedChangedListener checkChangedListener = new OnCheckedChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkId) {
        Object tag = group.getTag();
        if (!(tag instanceof Integer)) {
            // you have a bug. Fix it!
            return;
        }

        int position = (Integer) tag;
        Model model = getItem(position);

        switch(checkedId) {
        case R.id.radio_button_1:
            model.setCurrent(Model.ANSWER_ONE_SELECTED); break;
        case R.id.radio_button_1:
            model.setCurrent(Model.ANSWER_TWO_SELECTED); break;
        case R.id.radio_button_1:
            model.setCurrent(Model.ANSWER_THREE_SELECTED); break;
        case R.id.radio_button_1:
            model.setCurrent(Model.ANSWER_FOUR_SELECTED); break;
        }
    }
};
```

Now you just need to get your list of Models from the adapter.

Comment: The problem is that i don't know how to fetch all needed values in cycle and put it into array or something. And i don't realy get the difference between your soluton and the code i got so far except that i should store data in onCheckedChanged insteed of geting it on Button click. I did this to check what i can get during onCheckedChanged:

    Toast.makeText(getContext(),list.get(pos).question +" "+ list.get(pos).current, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

And it just showing some randow results.

Comment: Well you have a list of Model objects that you passed to the constructor of your adapter, so I assumed you had some data in them already (at least the question). How else could you show the question in the listview?